# Why i can't appeal to associated model attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I connected the models `product` and `cart_item`.

```
add_reference :cart_items, :product, null: false, foreign_key: true
```

schema.rb:

```
  create_table "cart_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "product_id", null: false
    t.bigint "cart_id", null: false
    t.index ["cart_id"], name: "index_cart_items_on_cart_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_cart_items_on_product_id"
  end
```

But when I try to create and refer to the model attributes, i get error:

```
undefined method `product' for #<CartItem:0x0000563873ac8a30>
Did you mean?  product_id
```

```
 a = CartItem.new
 a.product_id = 5
 a.cart_id = 1
 a.save
 a.product.title
 #NoMethodError (undefined method `product' for #<CartItem:0x00007ff110f96b50>) Did you mean?  product_id
a.product_id #=> 5
```

Comment: Can you share the code of `CartItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the information what you have shared I believe you have just added the Db migration but not the ORM (ActiveRecord) association in the model class.

```
class CartItem
  ...
  belongs_to :product #Hope you have a model named 'Product'
  ...
end
```

I believe adding the above line should fix the error.